# Is there a cleaner way to rotate smartphone images uploaded via flask before pushing to S3?

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm building a webapp that takes uploaded images, stores them on Amazon S3 and then stores the URL in a SQLite database. Unfortunately, EXIF tags cause images that were taken via a smartphone to appear rotated (since they are landscape images w/ EXIF orientation tags).

Currently, my environment grabs the file from the POST data, saves it to my static files folder, rotates image (if needed) with PIL, pushes to S3 and finally deletes the local copy. Here is a little of the code involved:

```
from PIL import Image
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

def fix_orientation(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    if hasattr(img, '_getexif'):
        exifdata = img._getexif()
        try:
            orientation = exifdata.get(274)
        except:
            # There was no EXIF Orientation Data
            orientation = 1
    else:
        orientation = 1

    if orientation is 1:    # Horizontal (normal)
        pass
    elif orientation is 2:  # Mirrored horizontal
        img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 3:  # Rotated 180
        img = img.rotate(180)
    elif orientation is 4:  # Mirrored vertical
        img = img.rotate(180).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 5:  # Mirrored horizontal then rotated 90 CCW
        img = img.rotate(-90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 6:  # Rotated 90 CCW
        img = img.rotate(-90)
    elif orientation is 7:  # Mirrored horizontal then rotated 90 CW
        img = img.rotate(90).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    elif orientation is 8:  # Rotated 90 CW
        img = img.rotate(90)

    #save the result and overwrite the originally uploaded image
    img.save(filename)

def push_to_s3(**kwargs):
    try:
        conn = S3Connection(app.config["S3_KEY"], app.config["S3_SECRET"])
        buckets = [bucket.name for bucket in conn.get_all_buckets()]
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(app.config["S3_BUCKET"])

        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = app.config["S3_UPLOAD_DIR"] + kwargs.get("filename")
        k.set_contents_from_filename(kwargs.get("photo"))
        k.make_public()
        return k
except Exception, e:
    abort(500)
```

Here is handling the POST data

```
# Retrieving Form POST Data
fi = request.files.get("file")

#print "Storing and Rotating File (if needed)"
f = photos.save(fi)
path = photos.path(f)
fix_orientation(path)

#print "Uploading to S3"
img = push_to_s3(photo=path, filename=filename)

#print "Deleting Local Version"
os.remove(path)
```

The above solution works on Heroku's servers, but it just seems very duct tape'd together of a solution. Is there are cleaner way to do what I'm doing. That is, take a uploaded file, rotate it from memory and then push to S3?

I'm also using Flask-Uploads to handle storage of the upload images.

Comment: It's worth noting that `is` is not guaranteed to work with numbers - they will *most likely* be cached, but it's not guaranteed (`is` compares `id` [identity] while `==` compares values)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The project involving this solution ended abruptly so I never was able to test your solution. Since mine worked, I assume this should as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it is worth, Pillow supports a number of other inputs than a file name - including [`bytearray`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray), [`buffer`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer), and [`file-like object`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open).  The third is most probably what you are looking for, as anything loaded out of [`request.files`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.files) is just a [`FileStorage`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) file-like object.  That simplifies the load-and-transform code to:

```
def fix_orientation(file_like_object):
    img = Image.open(filename)

    # ... snip ...

    data = BytesIO()
    img.save(data)
    return data
```

Since we are going to be passing around data without using the filesystem very much, we can also switch to using `boto.s3.key.Key`'s [`set_contents_from_file`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_file) method instead of `set_contents_from_filename`:

```
def push_to_s3(photo, filename):
    # ... snip ...
    k.set_contents_from_file(photo, rewind=True)
    # ... etc. ...
```

That simplifies the resulting implementation to:

```
# Retrieving Form POST Data
fi = request.files.get("file")

# print "Rotating File (if needed)"
fi = fix_orientation(fi)

# print "Uploading to S3"
push_to_s3(photo=fi, filename=filename)
```